# Validating req.params with express validator

Tags: javascript, api, express, endpoint, express-validator

I want the user to be able to write a specific account number in the endpoint, been trying to validate the endpoint param if it exists in my database. I couldn't get it to work, please what am I doing wrong?

> My validation

```
const validateReq: [
param('accountNumber').exists().custom(acctNo => accountNumberExist(acctNo)),]
```

> My accountNumberExist function

```
    accountNumberExist(inputAcct) {
    const isfound = accounts.find(account => account.accountNumber === inputAcct);
    if (isfound === undefined) throw new Error('Account Number not found');
  }
```

> My accounts file

```
    const accounts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    accountNumber: 1234567890,
    createdOn: new Date(),
    owner: 1,
    type: 'current',
    balance: 23444.43,
    status: 'active',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    accountNumber: 1234167890,
    createdOn: new Date(),
    owner: 1,
    type: 'savings',
    balance: 2233444.43,
    status: 'active',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    accountNumber: 9987654321,
    createdOn: new Date(),
    owner: 2,
    type: 'saving',
    balance: 73444.43,
    status: 'active',
  },
];
```

But this is always throwing the 'Account Number not found' error even though, the req.param exists in my accounts database.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Params are parsed as `string` by express middleware. Say I make a req to path defined below like `/some/1000`

```
app.get('/some/:path', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(typeof req.param.path)
  // outputs string
})
```

So you need to parse the incoming parameter to integer (Number) since you've stored `accountNumber` as integer. So adding `toInt` to chain like below should solve it:

```
const validateReq: [
  param('accountNumber').exists().toInt().custom(acctNo => accountNumberExist(acctNo)),
]
```

Comment: As the express-validator maintainer: this would be the preferred way of solving this ;)

Comment: what if i have value in param and in body?
eg: resetting password ->  we pass reset password token on param and email in body.
How can we deal such situations?

Comment: then wehere to use this sh*** validateReq variable?

Answer (score 1):

accountNumber inside accounts array is a number whereas req.params.accountNumber is a string. You need to convert the data type. You can do it as

```
    accountNumberExist(inputAcct) {
        const isfound = accounts.find(account => account.accountNumber.toString() === inputAcct);
        if (isfound === undefined) throw new Error('Account Number not found');
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem is your query. `find` method runs in an asynchronous way, that's why `isfound` property does not contain the data you expect. Here is a simple approach using `promises` which works pretty well for me.

```
// Here is your function.
accountNumberExist(inputAcct) {
    return accounts.find({accountNumber: inputAcct})
    .then(result => {
        if (result.length == 0) {
            console.log("Account Number not found");
            return Promise.reject('Account Number not found');
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    });

}
```

Comment: The OP is using plain arrays. No async stuff involved.

Comment: @gustavohenke where is the problem in this code? It is also recommended from the official docs https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html

Comment: As said above, the OP is using plain arrays, the `.find()` mentioned above is `Array.prototype.find` -- not some kind of DB query or API call.